# limited color in Morris chart

Tags: model-view-controller, morris.js

I want to draw Morris chart in my MVC View but my data are dynamic and more than 30 item i have, but morris chart just colors chart by 12 colors and repeat remaining slice and for my legend which i had create just for 12 colors display color like image which o attached. how can i use unlimited color for my chart?!

[image]

```
var ChartBlockShopFirstMelt = new Morris.Donut({
        element: 'MychartViewArea',
        parseTime: false,
        dataLabelsPosition: 'outside',
        resize: true,
        //donutType: 'pie',
        dataLabels: true,
        hidehover: 'auto',
        //colors: [
        //    '#882222'
        //    ],

            data: [
              @foreach(var item in ListAreaAndSheare )
                {
                    @:{ label: "@item.Lable", value: "@Math.Round(item.VALUE,2)" },
                }
    ],

    });

    ChartBlockShopFirstMelt.options.data.forEach(function (label, i) {
        var lgn = $('<span style=margin-left:10px;background-color:' + ChartBlockShopFirstMelt.options.colors[i] + '>    </span><br>').text(label['label']).prepend();
        $("#legendFirstMelt").append(lgn);
    });
```

Comment: Set the `colors` array property of your Morris donut chart with your colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an array of colors in the option **colors**.

Then for your legend, you can use modulo operator (%) to display the right color from that array.

In my example below:
**color_morris** is the array of color
**i** is the index parsed

```js
color_morris[i%color_morris.length]
```

Comment: ChartBlockShopFirstMelt.options.colors[i] to ChartBlockShopFirstMelt.options.colors[i%ChartBlockShopFirstMelt.options.colors.length]